# Expressing 28 as a sum of up to k numbers, where numbers are all $\leq$ 10

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

So lets say I have a set of numbers {1,2...,10}

I want to figure out how many ways I can use the numbers in the set to sum up to 28.

For example, a few ways are:
$$ 10+9+8+1 $$
$$2+5+6+7+8$$

A few things - you can't repeat numbers, so you cant do $10+10+8$ for example

So, order doesn't matter, and theres no replacement.

I know that the number of possibilities goes down by a factorial with every element you add to the sum.

But I'm not sure how to account for the fact that we don't care how many elements we use. We don't need to choose a specific k.

Any tips?

For context, the situation is one in which some person has 10 games to play to try and earn 28 points. Each game is 1...10, and if he wins the ith game, he gets i points.

The maximum total is 55 (if you add everything 1 to 10). A TA hinted to use the principle of symmetry, that if you have a sum of winning games that total to <28, then you can use the idea that 55-(<28) = a number greater than 28. Meaning, for every losing combination theres a winning combination.

SO, i guess we're supposed to find the "losing" combinations.

I'm thinking we have a bit string of length 10 where 0 represents a loss and 1 represents a win. Then I'm thinking since 55/2 = 27.5, we try to find the number of ways half of the bits are 0? But thats not gonna work

Comment: It can be done programmatically using knapsack dynamic programming. Not sure whether analytic expression exists

Comment: You are looking for the number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Odd_parts_and_distinct_parts) with distinct parts. You also have a maximum of $10$ parts, but this condition does not matter, as $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28$ with $7$ partitions, and you cannot have more than that. This is equivalent to the number of partitions with only odd parts as shown by Euler.

Comment: @TobyMak There is an additional condition that the parts do not exceed $10$.

Comment: @TobyMak that equivalence only applies if the parts are unrestricted, which is not the case here.

Comment: @saulspatz I have edited to reflect this.

Comment: @TobyMak hi sorry i wasnt super clear! We're allowed to exceed 28. so it can be greater than or equal to 28

Answer (score 1):

The number of possible sums we need to test in a naive approach is only $2^n$ and not $n!$ since numbers do not repeat. Since $n=10$, brute force is very much feasible:

```
count = 0
for n in range(1024):
    b = f"{n:010b}"
    l = [i+1 for i in range(10) if b[i] == '1']
    if sum(l) == 28:
        count += 1
        print(l)
print(count)
```

The result is that there are $40$ ways:

```
[5, 6, 8, 9]
[5, 6, 7, 10]
[4, 7, 8, 9]
[4, 6, 8, 10]
[4, 5, 9, 10]
[3, 7, 8, 10]
[3, 6, 9, 10]
[3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 4, 5, 7, 9]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 10]
[2, 7, 9, 10]
[2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 4, 6, 7, 9]
[2, 4, 5, 8, 9]
[2, 4, 5, 7, 10]
[2, 3, 6, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 6, 7, 10]
[2, 3, 5, 8, 10]
[2, 3, 4, 9, 10]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
[1, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9]
[1, 4, 6, 7, 10]
[1, 4, 5, 8, 10]
[1, 3, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 3, 6, 8, 10]
[1, 3, 5, 9, 10]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]
[1, 2, 7, 8, 10]
[1, 2, 6, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
40
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without code? like i think were supposed to use stars and bars but idk how

Comment: @MelanieSanders Stars and bars will not work. This is a partition problem, not a combination problem.